# Rfc2898DeriveBytes for java?

Tags: java, android, .net, encryption, rfc2898

My backend server is based on .NET. 
On the server there is use Rfc2898DeriveBytes encryption

This is the code of .Net

```
public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "abc123";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
```

I am writing the client in JAVA. This is the code

```
try {
        String encryptKey = "abc123";
        byte[] salt = new byte[]{0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76};
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(encryptKey.toCharArray(), salt, 1024, 128);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        System.out.println("Key:" + Base64.encodeToString(secret.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT));


        String cleartext = "12345";
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
        byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(cleartext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("IV:" + Base64.encodeToString(iv, Base64.DEFAULT));
        System.out.println("Cipher text:" + Base64.encodeToString(ciphertext, Base64.DEFAULT));;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidParameterSpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I do not get the same result in java as of .Net.
The encrypted value for `12345` is `dAQWIrbtHv/eDbu+4oJD0g==` on server.

While I get `tcvGLK5r99jt6PFLALpRfQ==`

What is the fix I need to apply?

Comment: You need to get the IV from PBKDF2 in Java, but you're always generating a random IV.

Comment: @ArtjomB. can you share the code if possible?

Comment: If you wrote all that code then you can probably make the changes too?  Or did you just copy and paste your security code?

Comment: @LukePark I did copied the code from this website - https://steelmon.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/simple-interoperable-encryption-in-java-and-net/

Comment: @WISHY did u find any solution?

Comment: @Androiddev i was able to solve it with some few adjustments also on the .Net code. Have pasted my solution below.

Comment: I tried getting keyBytes and ivBytes from java but it returns negative values in byte array, no idea why.

Comment: @arviman are using the answer which I had shared below or something else? I have also updated my answer if you may have problem with Base64.

Comment: I was just being an idiot @WISHY. I was verifying the output with the corresponding c# version where byte is unsigned, so I did have the correct answer in Scala (JVM) as well except byte is signed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with some few adjustments also to the .Net code.
Android code is as below

```
public class AES256Cipher {

private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] ivBytes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] textBytes)
        throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException {

    AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
    SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = null;
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
    return cipher.doFinal(textBytes);
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] ivBytes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] textBytes)
        throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException {

    AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
    SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
    return cipher.doFinal(textBytes);
}

final static String key = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv";

final static byte[] ivBytes = new byte[]{0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

public static String encryptData(String plainText) {
    String base64Text = "";
    try {
        byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] x = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] cipherData = encrypt(ivBytes, keyBytes, plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        base64Text = Base64.encodeToString(cipherData, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return base64Text;
}

//############## Response(decrypt) ##############
public static String decryptData(String base64Text) {
    String plainText = "";
    try {
        byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        try {
            byte[] cipherData = decrypt(ivBytes, keyBytes, Base64.decode(base64Text.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT));
            plainText = new String(cipherData, "UTF-8");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return plainText;
}
}
```

Simply call as below

```
String en = AES256Cipher.encryptData("1234");
        Log.e("enc length", en.length() + "");
        Log.e("enc", en);
        String de = AES256Cipher.decryptData(en);
        Log.e("dec", de);
```

For people using in java, can use the Base64 from package java.util
Replace in the encrypt method to this

```
base64Text =Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherData);
```

In decrypt method replace to this

```
byte[] cipherData = decrypt(ivBytes, keyBytes,Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Text.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Answer (score 4):

The default iteration count for `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is 1000, not 1024 (per [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rfc2898derivebytes.cs,46)).

And I don't know if the `keyLength` value for `PBEKeySpec` is in bytes, or bits, but if it's bits you've asked for 128 in Java and 256 (32-bytes) in C#.

Well, actually, you've asked for 384 bits in C#.  Because the first 256 become your cipher key, then the next 128 become your IV (which you seem to let get randomly generated in Java).

So, you probably need to ask for 384 bits, call `getEncoded()`, split the answer into a 32-byte key and a 16-byte IV, and proceed from there.